What is the "mean of logarithmic values" parameter in log-logistic distribution?
I was reading from mathworks site and it says:

The loglogistic distribution uses the following parameters.


However, the Wikipedia page of Log-logistic distribution says this distribution has two parameters namely, scale and shape. I'm a little confused, I'm wondering if there is a short name for "Mean of logarithmic values" or if it is possible to convert it to shape parameter. I am asking because I need to express this parameter in my work and I don't know how to refer to it convert this value to the known shape parameter.

The Wikipedia article you link to appears to answer all your questions up front in the Alternative parameterization section.

@whuber Yes I checked by plotting and the parameterization works: scale is $\exp(\mu)$ and the shape is 1/sigma.

By the way, the constraint $\mu>0$ in mathworks site seems wrong I think.

Wikipedia in effect describes the cumulative distribution functions as

for the logistic distribution: $P(X \le x)=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-(x-\mu)/s}}$
for the log-logistic distribution: $P(Y \le y)=\dfrac{1}{1 + (y/\alpha)^{-\beta} }$

where $\mu$ is the logistic mean (as you commented, this can be positive or negative or $0$), $s>0$ the logistic scale, $\alpha>0$ the log-logistic scale and $\beta>0$ the log-logistic shape.
If you treat these as equivalent when  $Y=e^X$ and $y=e^x$, so equating $e^{-(x-\mu)/s}$ and $(e^x/\alpha)^{-\beta}$, then you will have
$$\mu = \log(\alpha), s=\frac1\beta$$
and
$$\alpha = e^\mu, \beta=\frac1s$$
as Wikipedia describes as an alternative parametrisation of the log-logistic distribution.
